# is it possible to use tow ng-changes in one input field

Tags: angularjs

here is the code, i am trying to use two ngChanges, is it correct or any alternative way.

```
<select  ng-change="updatedate()"  ng-change="checkDate()" class="form-control" name="anniversaryMonth" ng-model="anniversaryMonth" month-options>
 </select>
```

Thanks,
Jameer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use 2 `ng-change`. Just seperate the functions with a `;`

```
ng-change="updatedate(); checkDate();"
```

Answer (score 4):

Call both the methods in single ng-change like this.

```
<select  ng-change="updatedate(); checkDate()" class="form-control" name="anniversaryMonth" ng-model="anniversaryMonth" month-options>  </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

use multiple operations in one `ng-change` and separate them by `;` like

`ng-change="updatedate();checkDate();"`

```
<select  ng-change="updatedate();checkDate();"  class="form-control" name="anniversaryMonth" ng-model="anniversaryMonth" month-options>
</select>
```

Comment: i guess you can't add `;` at the end `ng-change="updatedate();checkDate();"`

Answer (score 1):

There is no code error if we call two ng-change in same element like you configured :

```
<select  ng-change="updatedate()"  ng-change="checkDate()" class="form-control" name="anniversaryMonth" ng-model="anniversaryMonth" month-options>
 </select>
```

The problem is only it will not solve your purpose I mean you want to execute both function updatedate() checkDate() on change. It will only call first function you configured.

Now if you want to execute both function you will need to call both function with ';' separated in same ng-change.

You can check the difference in running [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FF9C18YQHXRD).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Write something in the input field:</p>
  <input type="text" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-change="myFunc1()" ng-model="myValue" />
  <p>two ng-change called for two function. value of count is {{count}} times.</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-change="myFunc();myFunc1()" ng-model="myValue" />
  <p>Two function call in one ng-change. value of count is {{count}} times.</p>
</div>



<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.count = 0;
      $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.count++;
        console.log('inc'+$scope.count);
      };
      $scope.myFunc1 = function() {
        $scope.count--;
        console.log('dec'+$scope.count);
      };
    }]);
</script>


</body>
</html>
```